# What traffic should be present in a Wireshark Capture when using a VPN?

Tags: vpn, wireshark

To start I am a full on novice at this so I am sure many on here can answer this simply. On my home network I am running a WRT router that is Flashed with Espress VPN, and the laptop I am running Wireshark on is running Linux Mint. To keep it simple let's just say I turn off all other devices connected to the network except for the laptop I am viewing Wireshark on, and do a capture on "any".  My question is prompted by the fact I am seeing it connecting to a lot of servers UDP and IPv6  even when no browsers or programs are running. At times there are even 5 or 6 NPT "time servers" connected at the same time as well. I kind of thought that the only thing I should see should be my connection to the Express VPN server as all my outgoing should be going there and all my incoming should be returning from there. Also most of the resolved names or ip's really seem to not be much of anything except webpages for smaller personal servers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I understand you correctly your VPN actually starts at the router only. Thus, every traffic you see on your local machine is outside the VPN.